# Aurora/Postgres multimaster?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am implementing Postgres Aurora to accept both interactive and batch input. If I was using RDS, I would use ClusterControl to implement multimaster replication, then use connection pools to establish node affinity. One notes that Multimaster for Aurora is MySQL-only. Does ClusterControl work with Aurora? Is there an alternative, or will I be forced to use RDS (or live with a single write master)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?